# White background shows when keyboard closes on Android

Tags: ionic-framework

I am testing my app on HTC One M8 running Android version 5.0.2. When an input field in the app loses focus, a white background is shown after the keyboard closes.

[image: GIF animation of issue recorded]

My background image is set on `.scroll-content`, so I don't understand why it acts like this on Android.

Comment: I had the same problem with Android 4.1.2 running on the stock browser Webview and the upgrade to Crosswalk fixed it. I also have a Nexus with Android 5 but I never saw that issue on Lollipop. That's weird.

Comment: Having the same issue here... Did you find any clean soluton? Thanks

Comment: Same issue was there ever a solution ?

Comment: Having same issue. Blue screen on keyboard close/screen rotation

Answer (score 2):

Check your ionic pane colour and view colour. You have different background colour so in the keyboard adjust pane mode the view gets resized (height-keyboard height) so when the keyboard goes off it shows the ionic-pane colour. So override the '.pane' background colour and see will it make any difference.

keyboard adjustment will work only if '.scroll-content' is present. By default ionic-content will enable this

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when we open a keyboard in our current application the app gets resized to the area that is left after opening the keyboard and the Cordova webview is too slow in resizing the app back to its normal size after the user closes the keyboard. There is no proper solution to this problem.

The most elegant working workaround for is to stop resizing the application on keyboard open. The keyboard will just slide up and down on the form as an overlay and there will be no resizing required.

In AndroidManifest.xml file try to set windowSoftInputMode attribute to adjustNothing:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This is not a solution and can be considered as an option for small forms but it is not suitable for big forms.